# How do you check if a function returns an object in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Example:

```
expect(bst.find(5)).toBe(<an object>);
```

And how can I make sure that it's an object with the following three properties: `val`, `left`, and `right`?

EDIT:

This works - http://jsfiddle.net/1d9h2L2z/1/

But this doesn't:

```
describe('A Binary Search Tree', function() {
  var bst;
  beforeEach(function() {
    this.addMatchers({
      toBeANode: function () {
        return this.actual.val !== undefined && this.actual.left !== undefined && this.actual.right !== undefined;
      }
    });
    bst = new BST();
    bst.insert(4);
    bst.insert(2);
    bst.insert(1);
    bst.insert(3);
    bst.insert(6);
    bst.insert(5);
    bst.insert(7);
    //       4
    //   2       6
    // 1   3   5   7
  });
  it('can do preorder traversal', function() {
    expect(bst.preorder()).toBe('4213657');
  });
  it('can do inorder traversal', function() {
    expect(bst.inorder()).toBe('1234567');
  });
  it('can do postorder traversal', function() {
    expect(bst.postorder()).toBe('1325764');
  });
  it('can do levelorder traversal', function() {
    expect(bst.levelorder()).toBe('4261357');
  });
  it('can get the minimum', function() {
    expect(bst.min()).toBeANode();
    expect(bst.min().val).toBe(1);
  });
  it('can get the maximum', function() {
    expect(bst.max()).toBeANode();
    expect(bst.max().val).toBe(7);
  });
  it('can find', function() {
    expect(bst.find(5)).toBeANode();
    expect(bst.find(5).val).toBe(5);
    expect(bst.find(10)).toBe(-1);
  });
  it('can findParent', function() {
    expect(bst.findParent(5)).toBeANode();
    expect(bst.findParent(5).val).toBe(6);
    expect(bst.findParent(8)).toBe(-1); // nonexistant node
    expect(bst.findParent(4)).toBe(-1); // root
  });
  it('can remove a leaf node', function() {
    bst.remove(7);
    expect(bst.inorder()).toBe('123456');
  });
  it('can remove a node with one child', function() {
    bst.insert(8);
    bst.remove(7);
    expect(bst.inorder()).toBe('1234568');
  });
  it('can remove a node with two children', function() {
    bst.insert(2.1);
    bst.remove(2);
    expect(bst.inorder()).toBe('12.134567'); // right subtree has a left subtree
    bst.insert(8);
    bst.remove(6);
    expect(bst.inorder()).toBe('12.134578'); // right subtree doesn't have a left subtree
  });
  // add AVL stuff
});
```

BST:

```
function BSTNode(val) {
    this.val = val;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
}
function BST() {
    this.root = null;
}
BST.prototype._isEmpty = function() {
    return this.root === null;
};
BST.prototype.insert = function(el, root) {
    var n = new BSTNode(el);
    if (this._isEmpty()) this.root = n;
    else {
        root = root || this.root;
        if (el < root.val) {
            if (!root.left) root.left = n;
            else this.insert(el, root.left);
        }
        else {
            if (!root.right) root.right = n;
            else this.insert(el, root.right);
        }
    }
};
BST.prototype.preorder = function() {
    var retStr = '';
    function innerPreorder(curr) {
        if (curr === null) return;
        else {
            retStr += curr.val;
            innerPreorder(curr.left);
            innerPreorder(curr.right);
        }
    }
    innerPreorder(this.root);
    return retStr;
};
BST.prototype.inorder = function() {
    var retStr = '';
    function innerInorder(curr) {
        if (curr === null) return;
        else {
            innerInorder(curr.left);
            retStr += curr.val;
            innerInorder(curr.right);
        }
    }
    innerInorder(this.root);
    return retStr;
};
BST.prototype.postorder = function() {
    var retStr = '';
    function innerPostorder(curr) {
        if (curr === null) return;
        else {
            innerPostorder(curr.left);
            innerPostorder(curr.right);
            retStr += curr.val;
        }
    }
    innerPostorder(this.root);
    return retStr;
};
BST.prototype.levelorder = function() {
    var retStr = '';
    var queue = [];
    queue.push(this.root);
    var curr;
    while (queue.length > 0) {
        curr = queue.shift();
        retStr += curr.val;
        if (curr.left) queue.push(curr.left);
        if (curr.right) queue.push(curr.right);
    }
    return retStr;
};
BST.prototype.min = function(curr) {
    curr = curr || this.root;
    while (curr.left) {
        curr = curr.left;
    }
    return curr;
};
BST.prototype.max = function(curr) {
    curr = curr || this.root;
    while (curr.right) {
        curr = curr.right;
    }
    return curr;
};
BST.prototype.find = function(val) {
    var curr = this.root;
    while (curr) {
        if (val === curr.val) return curr;
        else if (val < curr.val) curr = curr.left;
        else if (val > curr.val) curr = curr.right;
    }
    return -1;
};
BST.prototype.findParent = function(val) {
    if (this.root.val === val) return false;
    function innerFindParent(val, curr) {
        if (!curr.left && !curr.right) return false;
        if (curr.left.val === val) return curr;
        else if (curr.right.val === val) return curr;
        else {
            var retVal;
            if (curr.left) {
                retVal = this.findParent(val, curr.left);
                if (retVal) return retVal;
            }
            if (curr.right) {
                retVal = this.findParent(val, curr.right);
                if (retVal) return retVal;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    return innerFindParent(val, this.root);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a 'custom matcher'. The idea is that you create your own matcher function that can compare on specific values and more specific than just a standard isEqual matcher.
You can read more here: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/custom_matcher.html

Here's a fiddle for your specific case:
http://jsfiddle.net/1d9h2L2z/

```
//in your beforeEach you define your custom matcher:    
beforeEach(function () {
            this.addMatchers({
                // val, left, and right
                toBeAValidObjectPerDef: function () {
                    return (this.actual.val !== jasmine.undefined && this.actual.left !== jasmine.undefined && this.actual.right != jasmine.undefined);
                }
            })
        });


    describe('MyObject', function () {

        it('is a valid object with val, left and right', function () {
            // and here is how you can call it - instead of testObject you can use the one returned by your function
            var testObject = new TestObject('foo', 'leftValue', 'rightValue');
            expect(testObject).toBeAValidObjectPerDef();

        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! Why did you use `jasmine.undefined` instead of `undefined`?

Comment: Mostly because of copy & paste :)
But: in the Jasmine Sources there's a reason:
    /**
      * Use <code>jasmine.undefined</code> instead of       <code>undefined</code>, since <code>undefined</code> is just
 * a plain old variable and may be redefined by somebody else.
 *
 * @private
 */

Comment: I'm having trouble replicating your results in my file. Could you take a look at the edit to my question?

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Can you share what your BST looks like? especially the insert function. Are you using trevmex/bs.js?

Comment: Sorry, the fiddle I posted in the edit was wrong, it's updated now. The error I'm getting is 1) `TypeError: undefined is not a function` referring to `this.addMatchers` and goes away when I do `jasmine.addMatchers`. 2) `TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined` referring to `this.actual.val` and `expect(bst.min()).toBeANode();`.

Comment: I updated my question with my BST code (I still have to do the remove function).

Comment: Also, the [docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/custom_matcher.html) seem to say that you need a `compare` function but you don't. Why/how is that?

Comment: what version of Jasmine are you running? the 2nd error sounds like the object you pass in isn't defined. If you use karma as your test runner you should set it to use a browser and step through it in debug mode.

Comment: I'm using `2.1.3`. For the second, the object should be/is defined. The line after works - `expect(bst.min().val).toBe(1);`.

Comment: retVal = this.findParent(val, curr.left); // this.findParent isn't defined. That's because of scope issues ... - you need to make sure that this function can be accessed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69515/discussion-between-adam-zerner-and-birgit-martinelle).